# Casting in JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, chromecast

Does anyone know of a way to detect whether or not JWPlayer is casting media in the current session? I couldn't find an exact answer in any of their forums. I was messing around with the 'jwplayer.cast' namespace, but I couldn't find any methods that could be used to determine whether or not something was being casted at that time. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid we do not have any JavaScript API methods for Casting.

Comment: Could this be something possibly in the future that you guys can look into?

Comment: Indeed, when you brought this up, I thought it seemed like a good idea, so I made a feature request ticket internally to allow for a public api method for this. So yes, definitely possible in the future. I can't say if and when the team will do it, but I did put the request in, though.